# Spring Integration Flow Log on Outbound success

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

how can I add logs if file is transferred successfully.
I want to log file name and some values form my `config` object

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory()), e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron("0 */1 * ? * *").errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {
        try {

            // exception handling here
    })))
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(startup.deleteFileAdvice())
            )
            .get();
```

**Update**
after Gary Russell answer, my working code is

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory()), e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron("0 */1 * ? * *").errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {
           // action on exceptions are here
        }))).publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
            .subscribe(f -> f
                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                        .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(startup.deleteFileAdvice())
                ))
            .subscribe(f -> f
                .handle(m -> {
                    // all my custom logging logic is here
                })
            ))
            .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.publishSubscribeChannel()` channel with 2 subflows. [Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows).

```
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .handle(...)
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                            .log())
```

Comment: But for this use-case case we need to have those two subscribers in sync and one by one. So, the second one for log won't be called if some failure happens in the first one. So, `publishSubscribeChannel()` should be configured without an `Executor`.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am facing an issue. If i give cron of every one hour in poller.
it will pick all files after hours and transfer only one file instead of all.Transfer single file every hour. I was thing to check outbound cron but I am not sure its possible or not to give

Comment: Please don't ask new question in comments on old answers; it doesn't help people find questions/answers; you should always ask a new question. You need to increase `maxMessagesPerPoll` on the `poller` (it defaults to 1).